# Power Bi filtered export API is not working

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am working on a embeded powerbi within salesforce where i am using filtere which doing a export of file using rest api. The filter json looks like below . This is passed in the body of the POST request callout

```
{
    "format": "PDF",
    "powerBIReportConfiguration": {
        "ReportLevelFilters": [
            {
                "Filter": "User / Id in ('0055700000633IsAAI')"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Endpoint which i am calling is

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/reports/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/ExportTo

When the file is getting downloaded , i am getting all the data instead the filtered data. Anyting i am missing in the configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the spaces out of the Table/Column expression, per the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters), also some of your JSON names don't have the correct case. Here's the Fiddler capture of a successful request using the Power BI .NET Client:

```
{
  "format": "PDF",
  "powerBIReportConfiguration": {
    "reportLevelFilters": [
      {
        "filter": "DimCustomer/CustomerAlternateKey in ('AW00011000')"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So something like

```
{
    "format": "PDF",
    "powerBIReportConfiguration": {
        "reportLevelFilters": [
            {
                "filter": "User/Id in ('0055700000633IsAAI')"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: One big issue for us is that when a filter is invalid for whatever reason, all data is being returned. So if a filter is working today, and something changes in the data model, then the report will not error out but rather return all data, which is bad. Is there a way to error out the export if the filter is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue. I saw a post regarding a Power Automate flow which highlighted that when the report is published the filters need to be cleared. However even with this done, the `reportLevelFilters` do not seem to have an effect.

I have also tested the URL string params which work fine as per [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33691794)